# Accessing regex groups in view (mvc)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have a "PhoneNumber" string that I need to parse into 3 parts. I need each part to be displayed in separate fields within my view. I know how to accomplish this by adding other strings to the model, but the problem is that I no longer can do that. I need to be able to capture the parts using groups and access them through "PhoneNumber" somehow. Is this possible?

Model:

```
public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _phoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
            _phoneNumber = regexObj.Replace(value, ""); 
            var match = Regex.Match(_phoneNumber, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})");

            if (match.Success)
            {                        
                _phoneNumber = string.Format("({0}) {1}-{2}", match.Groups[1], match.Groups[2], match.Groups[3]);

            }

        }
    }
    private string _phoneNumber;
```

view (this is where I need to separate the groups):

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber, new { @id = "txtPhoneNumber", @Name = "txtPhoneNumber" })
```

Comment: what's wrong with the above code. what you are expecting?

Comment: @Venky all 10 digits display. I need to have a separate text box for the first 3 digits, the next 3 digits, and the last 4 digits in the view.

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have them displayed as three different text boxes you will need to have three different attributes on your model, as far as I know. So I would suggest having a Phone Number class with attributes Area Code, Exchange, Extension for example:

```
public class PhoneNumber {
    public string AreaCode {get;set;}
    public string Exchange {get;set;}
    public string Extension {get;set;}
}
```

You will then be able to have a view that has the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber.AreaCode, new { @id = "txtPhoneNumber_AreaCode", @Name = "txtPhoneNumber.AreaCode" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber.Exchange, new { @id = "txtPhoneNumber_Exchange", @Name = "txtPhoneNumber.Exchange" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber.Extension, new { @id = "txtPhoneNumber_Extension", @Name = "txtPhoneNumber.Extension" })
```

For the sake of reuse you could also make a PhoneNumber view and then when you need to use this editor again you can use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pharmacy.PhoneNumber)` instead of specifying this code throughout the entire application for all `PhoneNumber` classes. You could also keep your above regex to then separate the phone numbers into their `AreaCode`, `Exchange`, and `Extension`.

Comment: See I know about this method but I was looking to see If I could capture the incoming data from the db using the groups, and display them individually in my view. Wouldn't this force me to make changes to the stored procedure? because that's exactly what I'm not supposed to do.

Comment: @thatdude you wouldn't need to technically make changes to the database/stored procedure you would just need to split it out when reading from the database and join it together when placing it within the database. Which you could add another property that holds the joined string and create a `get` a `set` which joins/splits the incoming string. This value then could be what is saved/read from the database.

Comment: Your answer and the answer from another post just helped me figure out how I can achieve what I need. Thank you, good sir. :)

Comment: @thatdude no problem glad to hear.